# Elements in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Consider the projective line for simplicity. I was wondering was it means to look at the stalk at $0$. What is $0$ even referring to? The ideal generated by $0$ in one of the copies of the affine line? And if that is the case which one? Thanks for the help, even though this should be trivial.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In general people often view $\mathbb P^n$ as a plane $\mathbb A^n$ with extra points adjoint. For that you choose one of the $D_+(z_i)$ as your $\mathbb A^n$, normally the first or the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the projective line $\mathbb P^1$ as a one point compactification of $\mathbb A^1$. You take one of the standard open subspaces of $\mathbb P^1$, for example the space $D_+(x_0) = \{(x_0:x_1):\mathbb P^1|x_0\neq 0\}$ where the first coordinate does not vanish. That subspace is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1$ via the map which sends $t$ to $(1:t)$. The inverse sends $(x_0:x_1)$ to $x_1/x_0$. Now the $0$ in $\mathbb P^1$ is (relative to the arbitrary choice of $D_+(x_0)$ the image of $0\in\mathbb A^1$ under the inclusion $\mathbb A^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^1$. You get the point $(1:0)$. You can view the one point $(0:1)$ which isn't contained in $D_+(x_0)$ as the point $\infty =(0:1)$ at infinity. The stalk of $\mathbb P^1$ at $0$ can now be computed in the normal way, as a colimit over the rings $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P}(U)$ where $U$ ranges over the (Zariski, when you do scheme theory) open subspaces of $\mathbb P^1$ which contain $p$. It will be the case that
$$\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1,(1:0)}=\mathcal O_{\mathbb A^1,0} = k[x]_{(x-0)}$$
It is the ring $k[x]$ with inverses to all polynomials which do not vanish at $0$ freely adjoint.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Don't we have that $k[x]_{(0)}$ is just k(x) as we invert everything besides zero?

Comment: I think it does have an inverse. We have that (0)=$\{0\}$, so we invert everything besides 0, as $k[x]_{ (0) }:=\{k[x][\frac{1}{f}]|f\notin (0)\}$.

Comment: @Adronic oh, I am sorry. the right ideal to localize at is of course $(x-0)$ and not $(0)$. The zero ideal correponds to the generic point.

Comment: @Adronic I corrected it.

Comment: Ah i think now i understand it better. Thanks for your effort.